# Counting the number of nested directories with a unique name

Tags: bash

I have a mess of nested directories. The directories I am interested to count all have different names, but the good thing is that they all have a nested directory with a specific name. Therefore, it is possible to count the number of directories I am interested in by counting all the nested directories with that unique name:

Ex:

```
home/dir1/dir2/dir_of_interest_1/fruits
home/directory_of_interest_2/fruits
home/fruits
home/dir3/dir4/dir5/directory_of_interest3/fruits
etc...
```

I am interested in finding the number of "dir_of_interest_X", therefore, I would like to count the number of directories that have the name "fruits" inside 'home'. How would I do this in bash?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways.

Using `bash`'s recursive globbing:

```sh
shopt -s globstar
fruits=( home/**/fruits/ )
numfruits=${#fruits[@]}
```

This also gives you an array of all the fruits directories if you need it.

Using `find` and `wc` to get just the number:

```sh
numfruits=$(find home/ -type d -name fruits -printf "x\n" | wc -l)
```

If you don't want to count `home/fruits`, you can then subtract 1 from the total:

```sh
numfruits=$((numfruits - 1))
```